# Regular expression for XML Schema (number then 1 letter)

Tags: regex

#### I have the following requirements

- for use in XML Schema
- general format is a number followed by 1 letter
- should be case-insensitive

#### further restrictions:

- the valid letters are `[smhdw]`
- numbers are integers, no decimal parts allowed
- no leading or trailing whitespace

#### because it is XML Schema, the following is not allowed:

- lookaround
- modifiers like `(?i)`
- non-capturing groups

#### even further restriction:

- if `s` then the number can have a decimal part (unrestricted # of decimals)
- but I can live without this if it is too complicated to implement

#### examples

- `1s`
- `3m`
- `1.05s`
- `53.1345s`
- `5w`
- `37d`
- `101H`

can anyone help with this? thanks

Comment: _note to self:_ variant of the accepted answer that allows a `0` also (since this is a time expression and `0s` or `0d` is still `0`) ➟ `^(\d+([sSmMhHdDwW]|\.\d+[sS]))|0$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The first regex was, without testing, comparable in performance to other patterns that could achieve this. With updates to the parameters, this might be faster on large documents. Less backtracking

`^(\d+([sSmMhHdDwW]|\.\d+[sS]))$`

```
^                  # Anchors to beginning of line
(                  # opens capturing group 1
  \d+              # any number of digits, one or more
  (                # opens capturing group 2
    [sSmMhHdDwW]   # any of s,m,h,d,w (case-insensitive)
  |                # Alternation for capturing group 2
    \.             # Literal .
    \d+            # any number of digits
    [sS]           # s (case-insensitive)
  )                # closes capturing group 2
)                  # closes capturing group 1
$                  # Anchors to end of line
```

**Old patthern:**

`^(\d+(\.\d+)?[sS]|\d+[mMhHdDwW])$` should suit your needs

```
^            # Anchors to beginning of line
(            # Open Capturing Group 1
  \d+        # any digit, one or more times
  (          # open capturing group 2
    \.       # Literal .
    \d+      # any number of digits, 1 or more (denoted by +)
  )          # closes capturing group 2
  ?          # repeats previous group 0 or 1 times, thus optional
  s          # literal s
|            # Alternation
  \d+        # any digit, any number of times
  [mMhHdDwW] # character class, any of mhdw
)            # closes capturing group 1
$            # anchors to end of line
```

Comment: decimals for `s` are unrestricted

Comment: I get this error _XML Schema does not support non-capturing groups_ in RegexBuddy, so I guess that would be a further restriction - sorry I didn't know about that earlier

Comment: thanks, seems like it works - I added `^` and `$` to the start and end, to solve my no whitespace requirement and it doesn't seem to be case-insensitive so I changed it to this: `^(\d(\.\d+)?[sS]|\d[mhdwMHDW])$`

Comment: seems it works only on single digit numbers, how can we change this to work on say '55d` or `11.03s` ? I didn't think to include a multi-digit number originally in the examples

Comment: great, appreciate the help

Comment: @ycomp As your parameters became more defined, a different variant of this regular expression became superior in larger document. If it's a small operation, performance might not be noticeably different but larger documents may see an increase in speed.

New regex is at the top of the answer. If you want to give it a try

Comment: I like it, shorter too)